# How to get innerhtml value in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below html code

```
<div id="divTest">
    Hello
    <input type="text" id="txtID" value="" />
    <input type="button" onclick="getForm();" value="Click" />
</div>
```

And I have below javascript function to get innerHtml value

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getForm()
    {
        var obj = document.getElementById('divTest');
        alert(obj.innerHTML);
    }

    </script>
```

I am trying to get the complete innerHtml value. When user put some value in **"txtId"** and when he clicks on button it should show all the innerHtml with **txtId** value in it. It is working fine in Internet Explorer but failing in Mozilla.

Please suggest what type of changes I need to do in javascript function or I need some Jquery for this.

Thanks.

Best Regards,

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Expect StackOverflow questions to remain a beacon of light to the ages.  If aliens stumble across this question in 2525, what version of firefox would they learn was being used in our era? (click Help -> About)

Comment: I am using version 3.5.4 of Firefox

Comment: what type of error are you getting when you run your code in firefox

Comment: The IE is showing the txtID value what ever I enter in textbox however firefox is not showing the value.innerHTML is coming but without the value of textBox

Comment: Oh I see, I commented below in your answer... Mozilla will only find the first matching ID it finds and stop. If you are going to use duplicate object names, switch them to classes and not IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using below jQuery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">   



$(document).ready(function() 



 {

  var oldHTML = $.fn.html;



  $.fn.formhtml = function() {

    if (arguments.length) return oldHTML.apply(this,arguments);

    $("input,textarea,button", this).each(function() {

      this.setAttribute('value',this.value);

    });

    $(":radio,:checkbox", this).each(function() 

    {



      if (this.checked) this.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');

      else this.removeAttribute('checked');

    });

    $("option", this).each(function() 

    {      

      if (this.selected) this.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');

      else this.removeAttribute('selected');

    });

    return oldHTML.apply(this);

  }; 

  $.fn.html = $.fn.formhtml;

});

$(document).ready(function() 

{ 

    $('input[type=button]').click(function() {

        alert($('#divTest').html());

    });

});

    </script>
```

and the html was as below:

```
<div id="divTest">

    Hello

    <input type="text" id="txtID" />

    <input type="text" id="txtID" />

    <input type="text" />

    <input type="text" id="Text1" />

    <input type="text" id="Text1" />

    <input type="text" />

    <input type="text" />

    <input type="text" />

    <input type="text" id="Text5" />

    <input type="text" id="Text6" />

</div>

<input type="button" value="Click" />
```

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicate IDs

Answer (score 0):

I've run across this myself - try using `obj.innerHtml` (note capitalisation) instead.

Comment: its giving "undefined" after using obj.innerHtml. Please suggest

Comment: The proper case is infact `innerHTML`.